# Validate Payment Method in Magento 2

Tags: validation, payment, magento2

I want to check whether a customer is allowed to use one of the activated payment methods.

For example:

If the customer had enabled "Cash on Delivery", he should see the method but I can't find anything similar in the code.

In Magento 1 there was:

```
public function isAvailable()
```

Is there any similar way to do it with Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches you could take:

## Observer

If you take a look at `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` (the parent class of `\Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery`) in the `isAvailable` method, you will find that it dispatches the `payment_method_is_active` event which could be used to performs some additional logic (such as determine if a customer had enabled the specific method or not):

`$this->eventManager->dispatch(
    'payment_method_is_active',
    [
        'result' => $checkResult,
        'method_instance' => $this,
        'quote' => $quote
    ]
);`

## Plugin

Since `isAvailable` is a public method, you could add a plugin to the method. Whether you use before, after, or around depends on your specific needs. However, a good place for learning how to do this is the Magento DevDocs site: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html